# Telerik Ajax .net components IE rendering issue

Tags: .net, ajax, telerik, user-agent

I've been working in a Telerik ajax .net project and I'm using all different kind components. After deploying to server I realize that every telerik component are rendering with different aspect in IE 11 (locally everything looks nice) so I inspect and I'm getting no errors but when I emulate on EDGE It get better so I decide to force it in the web.config like this:

```
<add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge"/>
```

But still not rendering properly like It is locally on my machine. After emulate again I realize that **if I use the user Agent string to IE8 or above** it corrects everything.
Is there any workaround for this issue?
I'm using .net 4.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<html>
```

This one is quite different, try that and tell me if it makes any difference, it's what I'm currently using

Comment: I add the tag in the web.config file not in the page headers, I try and still the same.

Comment: I have that one in my master page